# Odoo 14 "my_method_name" is not valid action on "my_module_name"

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-14

I am learning odoo 14 and I am trying to add a button in my form view. Unfortunately, every time I try to upgrade my custom module I get this error:

```
odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: Error while validating view:

button_custom_method is not a valid action on library.book
```

My custom module python file **library_book.py**:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class LibraryBook(models.Model):
    _name = 'library.book'
    _description = 'Library Book'

    name = fields.Char('Title', required=True)
    date_release = fields.Date('Release Date')
    author_ids = fields.Many2many('res.partner', string='Authors')
    
    def button_custom_method(self):
        print("Button custom text")
```

And my view **library_book.xml**:

```
<odoo>
    <!-- Form View -->
    <record id="library_book_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Library Book Form</field>
        <field name="model">library.book</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <header>
                    <button name="button_custom_method" string="Please click me" type="object"/>
                </header>
                <group>
                    <group>
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="author_ids" widget="many2many_tags"/>
                    </group>
                    <group>
                        <field name="date_release"/>
                    </group>
                </group>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 4):

I Had the same issue than I realized that I had forgotten to import the file in the "__init__.py" file.

Answer (score 1):

Odoo will show this error message when there is [no function](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py#L1120-L1127) with the same name as your button on the view model where you defined the button.

```py
elif type_ == 'object':
  func = getattr(type(name_manager.Model), name, None)
  if not func:
      msg = _(
          "%(action_name)s is not a valid action on %(model_name)s",
          action_name=name, model_name=name_manager.Model._name,
      )
      self.handle_view_error(msg)
```

Probably, you defined the function on `library.book` model and you forgot to restart Odoo.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue right now. I didn`t solve it for half an hour, and then I realized, that I put button method in wrong model)

Answer (score -3):

Put `type="object"` first:

```html
<button type="object" name="button_custom_method" string="Please click me"/>
```